# Delphi Firedac Открытие запроса в ms access в TFDQuery

Tags: delphi, ms-access

В базе ms access есть созданный запрос.

При попытке открыть его в TFDQuery запрос открывается и выдает данные.

При запуске программы выдается ошибка следующего вида[image: Окно с ошибкой]

В чем тут проблема ?

Comment: в TFDQuery в режиме разработки запрос срабатывает и отображает данные а при запуске разрабатываемой программы выдается эта ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в Design time FDConnection отключить от БД и запустить программу.

Comment: Вы описываете ошибку которая возникает если источник данных недоступен при выполнении программы и доступен в Design Time при изначально включенном FDConnection. Если я в том же TFDQuery обращаюсь к таблице то все нормально а если к запросу, созданному внутри ms access то ошибка выше

Comment: в запросе есть параметры или join'ы? Запрос типа select * from пробовали?

Comment: да там простой select * никаких джойнов и тп, причем в дезигн тайм в свойствах TFDQuery запрос срабатывает, а в рантайме нет